# Simulate user browsing by code

Tags: php, python, linux, selenium

I need to simulate a user browsing a web-page like what selenium does, including loading iframes, making ajax requests etc..
The only problem it needs to run on a GUI-less machine (linux).
Is there a simple way to do this with python or php?
please don't tell me to use xvfb, I've already read about it, and it's my last resort.. I'm pretty sure that there should be something easier.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could use [Ghost.py](http://jeanphix.me/Ghost.py/) in Python:

```
from ghost import Ghost
ghost = Ghost()
page, extra_resources = ghost.open("http://jeanphi.fr")
assert page.http_status==200 and 'jeanphix' in ghost.content
```

This runs a headless Webkit browser that you can control from Python.