# Open specific "#" link that is processed by Javascript?

Tags: javascript, python, url

I want in Python to **visit** a link which is processed by JavaScript like the one below:

```
<a href="#" class="example"> Hello World </a>
```

I want to find the link from an HTML String based on the **class** attribute or the **id** attribute of the `<a>` Element.

Is it possible to do this in Python?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3075550/how-can-i-get-href-links-from-html-code

Comment: It's not clear what you're starting with, or exactly what you're asking. Do you have an HTML file and you want to parse out `href` attribute for various `<a>` tags in it? By "open a link", do you mean in a web browser, or in the background using something like `urllib2`?

Comment: I want to open a link with href="#" and class="example".... If the python script finds that the class is equal to "example", open it!

However, how can I open it when href is "#"?

Comment: A link with a hash wouldn't go anywhere if you need to trigger is with python you could use a headless browser

Answer (score 1):

You can't, because that is a self-referencing link. You have *already* opened the document.

A `#` in a URL signifies a location within a document. When the URL *starts* with a `#` it is location within the *current* document; the browser will scroll to whatever ID is named after the `#`. In the following example, clicking on the `<a href="#footer">` link instructs the browser to scroll the document to position the `<div id="footer">` element at the top of the browser window:

```
<a href="#footer">to the end of the document</a>

<!-- long document follows -->

<div id="footer">Something at the bottom of the document</div>
```

When the URL consists **only** of a `#`, the URL is a no-op. It is a placeholder, for JavaScript to intercept the link click usually. You can ignore it altogether when processing this document with Python. Your Python HTML parser is not a browser, no JavaScript is being run to handle the mouseclick on that link element. There is not even a mouseclick.

If you *are* trying to process a JavaScript-driven page, you could either use a JavaScript debugger (comes with most browsers) to figure out what it is doing, or run a headless browser controlled by Python. You could use [Ghost.py](http://jeanphix.me/Ghost.py/) to do the latter:

```
from ghost import Ghost
ghost = Ghost()
page, extra_resources = ghost.open("http://jeanphi.fr")
assert page.http_status==200 and 'jeanphix' in ghost.content
```

This runs a headless Webkit browser.

Comment: Isn't there any library to do this? Mechanize or any other library?

Comment: See [Simulate user browsing by code](http://stackoverflow.com/a/15177624)

Comment: Thanks, I will try it out and report if It worked for me!